# Routing on Centos configration

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, centos, redhat

i need to setup routing rule.
this is what i need to do:

```
ip route add default via 172.31.32.1 dev eth1 tab 2
ip rule add from 172.31.38.228/32 tab 2
ip rule add to 172.31.38.228/32 tab 2
```

i'm using Centos 7.
this routes for AWS.

how can i setup it that it will work after reboot?

Comment: Can you explain after reboot means when do you have to set it up?

Comment: 1. i don't how to setup it to be forver.

Comment: 2. after reboot, the route and rule gone

Comment: After reboot of the server you mean to say right?

Comment: yes, so how can i setup this configraion?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a executable script file "example.sh"
2. Type in command `crontab -e`
3. Add this line `@reboot /path/to/example.sh`

example.sh will have your commands below. And thats it at each reboot those commands will be executed.

```
ip route add default via 172.31.32.1 dev eth1 tab 2
ip rule add from 172.31.38.228/32 tab 2
ip rule add to 172.31.38.228/32 tab 2
```

Comment: i think it's not good solution. i know that can be placed. on : /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-eth1

Comment: For your use case that is the best solution there is not other way when you can run those commands automatically after reboot. the other way you have to run those commands manually each time.